# mount: special device /tmp/cdrom does not exist - CentOS kickstart %post section

Tags: linux, centos, mount, kickstart

I am upgrading an installation from CentOS 5.5 to 6.4.  I am having troubles with my kickstart file in the %post section while mounting /tmp/cdrom during the install:

The following configuration in ks.cfg worked fine in CentOS 5.5..But, now takes a dump in 6.4...

ks.cfg:

```
#
# Post install tasks to ready the system for the installation of PressureMap
#
%post --nochroot  --log=/mnt/sysimage/root/ks_post.log
#
# Copy additional files to the installed system
#
echo "Copying files to installed system..."
# mount the install disk
mkdir -p /mnt/source
mount -t iso9660 /tmp/cdrom /mnt/source
```

What has change from CentOS 5.5 to 6.4?? Not sure what I need to do here?? I see the error in my ks_post.log file:

```
Copying files to installed system...
mount: special device /tmp/cdrom does not exist
```

Answer (score 2):

Not being a CentOS user, I can't say why `/tmp/cdrom` would have existed in the first place, but it seems weird.  Presumably it was a symlink to a real device node.  You might try `grep -R cdrom /etc/udev/` to see if someone set this up.

There's probably a parallel symlink at `/dev/cdrom`, so you should be able to use that instead.

Comment: I was able to eliminate the mount because the drive was already mounted. Everything works fine now.. Thx for the input..